# `brew doctor` shows warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories

Tags: macos, ruby

When I use `brew doctor`, I get following error.

```
Warning: "config" scripts exist outside your system or Homebrew directories.
`./configure` scripts often look for *-config scripts to determine if
software packages are installed, and what additional flags to use when
compiling and linking.

Having additional scripts in your path can confuse software installed via
Homebrew if the config script overrides a system or Homebrew provided
script of the same name. We found the following "config" scripts:

    /Users/${username}/.rbenv/shims/passenger-config
```

The config file seems to be related ruby, not homebrew.

What should I do to remove this error?

Comment: were you ever able to fix this?

Comment: After reinstalling OSX, the error is disappeared. So, eventually I couldn't find out how to fix it.

Comment: ahh bummer :( wish we knew the answer.

Answer (score -1):

Answer in StackOverflow question [How can I stop homebrew from complaining about *-config files in $PATH?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20144348/how-can-i-stop-homebrew-from-complaining-about-config-files-in-path)

Essence is

- it is only a warning
- Homebrew community [treat this purely as a warning and are happy enough to leave it in place](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew/issues/18552)